# How to move backwards between windows?

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows

`Ctrl-w w` moves to next window. `Ctrl-w p` is not the symmetrical of `Ctrl-w w`, it moves to last window at first, but then moves back to where it was.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3):

`Ctrl-w W` (capital `W` on the second time)